# PhpStorm wrapping multiple lines in list tags

Tags: list, html-lists, phpstorm, word-wrap

Hi StackOverflow community!

Straight to the point! I currently have in PHPStorm...

```
<ul>
 Content
 Content
 Content
 Content
 Content
 Content
</ul>
```

Content obviously serving as a placeholder... 
At the moment im going through these lines individually implemented list tags on every line,  which is extremely slow as I'm current created a heck load of lists!

Anybody got any sugguestions on how to speed up this process considerably?
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use **Emmet** (previously known as Zen Coding) for this.

**Code | Surround with... | Emmet**

[image]

If you have `<ul>` tags already created, just alter string a bit (i.e. `li*`). More details/documentation is available here: http://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/

Comment: Brilliant! This solved my answer instantly, now reading thoroughly through the documentation you provided me! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If you have enabled **Emmet** and prefer shortcuts you can:

1. select text
2. press 2x `Shift`
3. type `Surround` and select `Surround with Emmet`
4. in input type `li*` and press `Enter`