# How can I surround a text with a tag in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm

How can I surround a text with a tag in WebStorm? Like if I select a text and click something which allows me to type a tag name ? Command + Alt + T does not allow me to do so in a Mac OS

Comment: `Cmd + Alt +T` should work on Mac: see 1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/24304889/783119 and 2) https://stackoverflow.com/a/20095020/783119 3) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/editing-html-files.html#ws_html_surround_code_fragment_with_tag (choose your Keymap there if needed)

Comment: What shortcut do you have for `Main menu | Code | Surround With`? That shortcut should work if you select the text in the editor and invoke it. If it still does not work -- go to `WebStorm | Preferences | Keymap` -- there is a button next to the local search field, it allows to search for action by assigned shortcuts -- use it and see what action is assigned to that shortcut / maybe it does not recognize such key combo at all?